# Prove Limit to Infinity using Epsilon-N proof

Tags: calculus

Prove;  $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2 +1} = 0$$

I know very well how to prove this using the sandwhich theorem, but we are asked to use the Epsilon-N proof.

My attempt was recall the definition, which seems to be; "$ \forall\epsilon, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N$ implies  $ |f(x) - L| < \epsilon.$ ", I've done many normal limit proofs by defintion, but don't know how to prove this one. My first attempt was me trying to work from $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ to show that given $\epsilon$ we can derive some $N$ (in terms of $\epsilon$) since that's what we did with the other proofs.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the fact that $\cos(x)$ is bounded by $1$ for all $x$, so $\bigg|\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+1}\bigg| \leq \bigg|\frac{1}{x^2+1}\bigg|$ and use the Epsilon N-proof on the later part.